# Get the current possible accepted bounds of a variable after having defined several constraints in a linear problem

Tags: python, debugging, linear-programming, or-tools

Based on the following simple example of linear problem, how would you retrieve the possible accepted bounds of the variable `x` after having applied some constraints on it? It should return two parameters:

1. The minimum possible value (61.0)
2. The maximum possible value (93.0)

Using `x.lb()` and `x.ub()` returns the bounds that were assigned to the variable at its creation but does not take into account the constraints that are applied on it.

```
from ortools.linear_solver import pywraplp
# Create the linear solver with the GLOP backend.
solver = pywraplp.Solver('lp_pricing_problem', pywraplp.Solver.GLOP_LINEAR_PROGRAMMING)
# Define a variable with a range from 0 to 1000.
x = solver.NumVar(0, 1000, 'MyVariable')
# Define some constraints on it.
solver.Add(x <= 147)
solver.Add(x <= 93)
solver.Add(x >= 61)
solver.Add(x >= 17)

print(x.lb()) # 0.0
print(x.ub()) # 1000.0

# Minimize x
objective = solver.Objective()
objective.SetCoefficient(x, 1)
objective.SetMinimization()

status = solver.Solve()

# Print the solution
if status == solver.OPTIMAL:
    print(x.solution_value()) # 61.0
```

The real purpose of this question is to understand why the solver returns an INFEASIBLE status when, for example, the constraints are not properly defined:

```
solver.Add(x <= 147)
solver.Add(x <= 93)
solver.Add(x >= 61)
solver.Add(x <= 17)
```

In such a situation, I would like to see that the variable `x` must below or equal to 17 and at the same time above or equal to 61. If you think about a better way to debug this kind of issue, please don't hesitate to share it here.

Many thanks in advance for your help and ideas.

Romain

Answer (score 4):

Set it as the objective. Minimize and maximize this variable.

Comment: Hi Laurent, Thanks a lot for your answer. However, this only works if the solution can be found, is it right?
In the second part of the question, this constraint would make it fail: `solver.Add(x <= 17)`

Is there a way to get the best solution found by the optimiser when the status in INFEASIBLE ?

Comment: It does not make sense, there are no solution found.

Comment: Yes, my comment was not correct. I should have said: 
When we have `status == solver.INFEASIBLE`, how can we get the range obtained by applying the constraint on `x`?

In other words, find that the variable `x` must be below or equal to 17 and at the same time above or equal to 61.

Comment: There are no good solutions. You can scan linear constraints with only one variables. But then you will want to deduce that if x + y >= 10, then x >= 10 - max(y)... Going along, you will want a full propagation.

Comment: To make my point clearer, suppose you write x >= 10; x <= 5. What are the best lower and upper bounds for x ?

Comment: I have nearly 10000 constraints and 150 variables. Most of the time, the optimiser can find an optimal solution but it might happen that two (or more) constraints are causing a `x >= 10; x <= 5` and thus we obtain a `solver.INFEASIBLE`. In such a situation, I would like to have a way to find which variable(s) and which constraints are causing the infeasible result. This is why I created this ticket. But according to your answers, I cannot directly obtain the values I need. The only solution that I have currently, is removing the constraints one per one to find which ones are causing the issue

Comment: For example, if I had only a single variable `x` and two constraints, `x >= 10; x <= 5` would return something like "INFEASIBLE because of x=[>= 10 and <= 5]". If instead of these two constraints, I had the two following `x <= 10; x >= 5`. It would return something like "Optimal with 5<=x<=10". But to be honest, I am only interested in this output for infeasible situations.